# MVVM Toolkit for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am trying to learn Windows Phone 7 and the MVVM pattern. One of the books I been reading showed how to do MVVM but said in the end you should opt for a framework to help reduce redundant code.

In the book they showed MVVM Light took kit. I watched the videos but they are just too hard to follow along(downloading the source codes does not help that much as I get very fast lost in it).

I tried finding tutorials and going through the one in the book but it seems like MVVM light has gone through quite a few changes making the tutorials very hard to follow.

I then looked at Simple MVVM and it looked promising but it looks like the author does not have that much time anymore and looks like the project might be dead(so when I go to windows 8 phones or windows 8 app I got to learn a new toolkit...)

I am looking for something simple and that has lots of tutorials and goes far beyond just the basics.

What I found with MVVM light is that you see him talk about how you can basically not have to use code behind(ie for navigation) but since there are no tutorials on how to show you step by step to do this it makes it very hard to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a navigation solution, take a look here: http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2011/01/06/navigation-in-a-wp7-application-with-mvvm-light.aspx it also has a link to a blog post by Jesse Liberty, that post is one out of a series showing you how to use MVVM light when creating a wp app!